# What's the maximum euclidean distance between 2 hyperpoints in word2vec algorithm?

Tags: math, machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec

I have been considering to use Word2vec for a problem.
I know that you can use cosine distance which means the minimum distance can be 0 if the hyperpoints are identical or 1 because cosine spans from [-1,1] in case of maximum.
The same applies for minimum in euclidean distance.
My question is in practice what is the maximum euclidean distance two said words can achieve while using word2vec to project them in the same hyperspace ? Can it be estimated mathematically ? is it theoretically infinite ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The training process doesn't necessarily bound where a word-vector winds up, so I believe the euclidean-distance between two words could become arbitrarily large.

But, they'd only get arbitrarily large with arbitrarily many training passes, and perhaps only on certain extreme training corpuses. The normal variety of language and limited number of training passes means that in practice vectors don't get *too* far from the origin point.

It's common to unit-normalize the word-vectors, so that they all have a magnitude of 1.0 (and thus are on the "unit-hypersphere"), before making word-to-word comparisons. If you've done this normalization:

- while the euclidean-distance and cosine-distance will be different values, the *rank order* of nearest-neighbors will be the same no matter which you use
- the maximum distance between any two vectors would be 2, for points diametrically opposite each other on the hypersphere

Answer (score -1):

It would depend on the number of dimensions of your vector at the very least. Even it were normalized to 0-1, the max distance would be sqrt(n), where n is the number of dimensions you choose in your vector. And so even in that case, it would be unbounded.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the number of dimensions. If the vectors are all unit-normalized then the maximum distance is 2.0. But yes, I'm pretty sure the distance between raw vectors could grow to be unboundedly high, with an unbounded amount of training and sufficiently peculiar training corpus.